# In Rmd documents rendered to pdf, preventing extra line breaks in R chunks?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

The following code results in an extra line break between `rnorm(1)` and the return value. How do I remove this extra line?

````
---  
title: "Lecture2"  
output: pdf_document  
---

```{r}  
rnorm(1)  
```
````

I have miktex installed and am using knitr.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should evaluate as inline code (i.e. `r norm(1)`).

Comment: I want the statement to display as well.  Inline code only shows what the return value.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works only when highlight=FALSE and has the unfortunate side effect of removing the ability to create line breaks with new paragraphs...

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---

```{r, highlight=FALSE}  
rnorm(1)  
```
````

in header.tex

```
%code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43331/control-vertical-space-before-and-after-verbatim-environment
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt }
\makeatother


%https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Paragraph_formatting
\setlength{\parskip}{0 em}
```